# Looking in a Discord message for bad words?

Tags: python, discord

I am currently trying to make my own Discord bot (I'm not very good) and I want to filter the messages the bot gets for bad words. So what I researched and tried was this:

Here I made another Python script for the words because I wanted to keep the code organized. The other script is a simple list.

```py
from badwords import *

if badwords.badword in message:
     await message.channel.send('Thats not nice! STOP!')
```

I also tried the `any()` method but I removed that and now I don't have that anymore and it didn't work too.

Comment: In this instance is `badword` the word or is it a list.

Comment: badword is a list.

Comment: `message in badwords.badword`?

Comment: Err. I think it would be 
`
message_words = messag.split(\n\r\f\s...);
for word in message.words:
 if word in badwords.badword
` You will need to find the code to properly split the words, but this gives a starting point.  I do not know about Discord API so there may be more to message

Answer (score 0):

Is the message a string? Or is it in a list too?
If it is in a string, what you can do is split the string, make it into a list where each word is an entry and check each word.

```
#  creating a list of the words
words = message.split()
for word in words:
    if word in badwords.badword:
        await message.channel.send('Thats not nice! STOP!')
```

(Note: This will work but there are probably better ways of doing this too.)

Comment: I understand `badword` is a list. I was asking about `message`. Anyhow, the code should work if `message` is a string.
Full disclosure - I haven't worked with Discord API so I don't have too much idea about how it works.

Comment: sorry, i understood that wrong. `message` is a string if you use `message.content`

Answer (score 0):

I've experimented with the library you used and it seems like that library is a Chinese profanity filter. (Judging by what I've found out... It also doesn't seem very well documented.) `badwords.badword("text", "/path/to/wordlist.txt")` just puts the negating word 不 (bù) before words from the wordlist.

What you're more probably looking for is something like [`better_profanity`](https://pypi.org/project/better-profanity/):

```py
from better_profanity import profanity

profanity.contains_profanity("fuck this shit")
# returns True


profanity.contains_profanity("Would you like a cup of tea, sir?")
# returns False


# better_profanity also detects 1337 speech
profanity.censor("fVcK this 5h17, I'm out!")
# returns "**** this ****, I'm out!"
```

Comment: I know this question was asked ~2 months ago by the way. I just hope I can help others stumbling upon it.